# Set global instance of toastmessage using akquinet jquery toast message plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was using [jquery plugin](http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/) to show toast message on the click of a button given a certain condition. But as and when I click on the button new toast message is shown. What I want to show is just one toast message being shown on the click of that button meaning, it should not show another toast message when my first toast message is still on the screen.

Is there some way to have global instance of it and then showing the same each time rather than show new one ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to remember if the toast message is displayed. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrvsy6kk/1/) (forked from the official [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/QCs6n/)). You could also use the myToast variable as "boolean" in a similar way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var isDisplaying = false;
    var yourText = 'Success Dialog which is NOT sticky',
        toastMessageSettings = {
            text: yourText,
            sticky: false,
            position: 'top-right',
            type: 'success',
            closeText: '',
            close: function() {
                console.log("toast is closed ...");
                isDisplaying = false;
            }
        };


    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
     if ( ! isDisplaying) {
          var myToast = $().toastmessage('showToast', toastMessageSettings);
          console.log('myToast:');
          console.log(myToast);
          isDisplaying = true;
        }
        
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/demo/jquery.toastmessage-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/demo/css/jquery.toastmessage-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <h1><a href="http://github.com/akquinet/jquery-toastmessage-plugin">jquery-toastmessage-plugin Demo</a>
        <br/><span class="small">by <a href="http://github.com/akquinet">akquinet</a></span></h1>

<button id="mybutton">Press it</button>
```